# Arduino library or code for ESP32 to scan for Bluetooth devices?

Tags: esp32, bluetooth, library, ble

Is there some code or library that would allow me to scan for nearby Bluetooth devices using a common ESP32 board ?
I only found similar code for actual Arduino boards.

Comment: a web search reveals some

Comment: Well.. now this question is answer #4 in a web search and 2 of the answers above are for BLE only and the other one leads to another unanswered question. It is not that easy to find good example because the Arduino-ESP32 framework added advanced Bluetooth support just recently - and its not that easy to use the receent versions.

Comment: @IanH Almost two years later, there is an actual solution to this. See gbafamily's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The ESP32 Arduino boards support package includes libraries for ESP32 Bluetooth and BLE. Both libraries have examples which you can find in Arduino IDE Examples menu.

Comment: I looked trough the examples but I didn't see one that lists nearby devices, just various example on how to pair with specific device.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/esp32beans/ESP32-BT-exp is a Bluetooth Dual
Mode (classic and BLE) scanner. ESP32-BT-exp works on the original ESP32. No other ESP32 supports BT classic mode.

Comment: Worked as promised! How unfortunate that it is *only * ESP32, and not ESP32S2/S3 or ESP32C2/C3. (Cue rant on Espressif's naming conventions...)